# Message keeps repeating through every element of array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new at Java and I have an array of objects of Passenger constructor class. I'm trying to display an error message if a Passenger object is being created and the birth date inserted isn't in the correct format I specify below. The problem is the error message keeps repeating through the entire array when I only have one birth date not formatted correctly.

This is my main class:

```
public class IPOO_P2 {

    private static Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SubwayManager man1 = new SubwayManager(passengers);

        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {

            passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee", "12", "2011-10-02");
            passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "1", "1957-10-02");
            passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");
            passengers[i] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
            passengers[i] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
        }
    }
}
```

The Passenger class:

```
public class Passenger {

    private String name;
    private String nif;
    private String birthDate;
    private Trip[] tripsLog;
    private boolean student;

    public Passenger(String name, String nif, String birthDate) {
        if (name != null || name != "") {

           if(isDateValid(birthDate)) {
               
                this.name = name;
                this.nif = nif;
                this.birthDate = birthDate;
                this.student = false;
                this.tripsLog = new Trip[10];
                
            } 
           else{ 
               System.out.println("Birth Date formatt should be: yyyy-MM-dd");
           }
        }
    }

    public boolean isDateValid(String bDate) {

        if(bDate != null){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

        try {
            LocalDate.parse(bDate, formatter);
            return true;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {

            return false;
        }
    }return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need that `for` loop in `main`. Enter the numbers: `passengers[0] = new Passenger("nomee", "12", "2011-10-02");`, etc.

Comment: You need to show us `SubwayManager` code. `passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");` is the only value you ever insert into your array, I suspect the 2 lines following it don't do a thing to the array contents while the 2 lines before it do not matter since `passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");` is what is inserted at index i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your For loop is repeatedly executing the code that constructs the `Passenger` objects 10 times. So you will see the same error message displayed for 10 times if there is one bad date in a `Passenger` constructor.

Remove the `For loop` from the code creating the `Passenger` objects and create the `Passenger` objects individually like so:

```
            passengers[0] = new Passenger("nomee", "12", "2011-10-02");
            passengers[1] = new Passenger("nomee2", "1", "1957-10-02");
            passengers[2] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");
            passengers[3] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
            passengers[4] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
```

That way you will see the error message just one time for each bad date supplied to a `Passenger` constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do here

```
passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee", "12", "2011-10-02");
passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "1", "1957-10-02");
passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");
passengers[i] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
passengers[i] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
```

You are overwriting the ith element in the passengers array 4 times each loop.

This assignment is giving a `DateTimeParseException` and hence the same is being printed for each iteration:

```
passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this block:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {

            passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee", "12", "2011-10-02");
            passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "1", "1957-10-02");
            passengers[i] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");
            passengers[i] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
            passengers[i] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
        }
```

You are running all the lines for every loop step. I mean, if the array has 10 elements, and inside the loop you all paserngers[i] 5 times. You are running 10*5 = 50 array assignations.

Each and every passenger[i] (but the first one) overrides the previous one.

For instace, in the first iteration, i = 0. So you run:

```
            passengers[0] = new Passenger("nomee", "12", "2011-10-02");
            passengers[0] = new Passenger("nomee2", "1", "1957-10-02");
            passengers[0] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");
            passengers[0] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
            passengers[0] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
```

In the second iteration:

```
            passengers[1] = new Passenger("nomee", "12", "2011-10-02");
            passengers[1] = new Passenger("nomee2", "1", "1957-10-02");
            passengers[1] = new Passenger("nomee2", "0", "19-101-02");
            passengers[1] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
            passengers[1] = man1.createPassenger("name", "3", "1997-10-02");
```

And like that, 10 times. In very one of the iterations you call the constructor with the wrong date (apart from the other 4 with the correct day).